# On number of coprimes in a bounded interval - I

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

If you pick a pair of integers then you can be guaranteed that they are coprime with probability $\frac1{\zeta(2)}$.

However if you fix $a\in\Bbb N$ and pick a pair in $[a,2a]$ what is the probability that they will be coprime?

For general $k$-tuples instead of pairs it is asked in [On number of coprimes in a bounded interval - II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4448780/on-number-of-coprimes-in-a-bounded-interval-ii).

Comment: Probably still $1/\zeta(2)$... at least asymptotically.

Comment: @Wojowu is it clear? it is not clear if it were primes instead of coprimes.

Comment: It is rather immediate from PNT that there are $\sim\frac{a}{\log a}$ primes in $[a,2a]$, if this is what you mean, but I don't see it as quite as obvious that the result I've stated is true (which is why I've said "probably").

Comment: If you know how to get $1/\zeta(2)$ then you know how to write explicit answer to your question.

Comment: integer points with coprime coordinates are equidistribured on the plane in the sense that for any Jordan domain $Q$ the number of coprime points in $tQ$ grows as $t^2|Q|/\zeta(2)$ for large $t$. Apply this to $Q=[1,2]^2$

Comment: The Lehmer's paper [1900] has some related results. I think it will be helpful...

Comment: Fedor Petrov, can you give me a reference to that Jordan domain result? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we establish asymptotic number of coprime pairs $(a,b)$ with $1\leq a\leq c_1n,1\leq b\leq c_2n$ with $c_1,c_2$ positive constants (this is well-known for $c_1=c_2$, and the argument seen [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/97047/30186) generalizes, but I add it here for completeness). Note that
$$\sum_{d\mid a\text{ and }d\mid b}\mu(d)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if }\gcd(a,b)=1,\\
0 & \text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$
so the number of pairs in question is
$$\sum_{a\leq c_1n,b\leq c_2n,d\mid a,d\mid b}\mu(d)$$
$$=\sum_{d\leq N}\mu(d)\sum_{k\leq c_1n/d , l\leq c_2n/d}1$$
$$=\sum_{d\leq N}\mu(d)\left(\frac{c_1c_2n^2}{d^2} + O\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)\right)$$
$$=c_1c_2n^2\sum_{d\leq N}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}+O(n\log n)$$
$$=c_1c_2n^2\sum_{d=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}+O(n\log n)$$
$$=c_1c_2n^2\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}+O(n\log n)$$
where $N$ is taken to be the larger of $c_1n,c_2n$. Applying this with $(c_1,c_2)$ equal to, in order, $(1,2),(2,1)$, adding these and subtracting for $(1,1)$, this gives precisely the number of coprime pairs in $[a,2a]^2$, which is seen to be equal $n^2\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}+O(n\log n)$.

Comment: Dear Wojowu, this is great. One can generalize this argument to any rectangle not necessarily on the main diagonal, as long as the rectangle is not too small compared to its distance from the origin. Then the Jordan domain result mentioned above by Fedor Petrov follows by dividing the shape into rectangles. Do you know of any reference I can cite for these results?

Comment: @wojowu So instead of $2$ if we had $k$ numbers and ask if they are coprime, is the number of $k$ tuples $c_kn^k/\zeta(k)+o(n^k)$?

Comment: @wojowu Asked in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4448780/on-number-of-coprimes-in-a-bounded-interval-ii.