# On number of coprimes in a bounded interval - II

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

If you pick $k$-tuples of integers then you can be guaranteed that they are coprime with probability $\frac1{\zeta(k)}$.

However if you fix $a\in\Bbb N$ and pick $k$-tuple in $[0,a]$ what is the probability that they will be coprime?

For $k=2$ it was answered in [On number of coprimes in a bounded interval - I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005279/on-number-of-coprimes-in-a-bounded-interval).

Comment: The probability will converge to $1/\zeta(k)$ as $a\to\infty$

Comment: Can  you provide an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N_k(a)$ denote the number of $k$ tuples in $[0,a]$ that are coprime, then by definition, we have

\begin{aligned}
\lfloor a\rfloor^k
&=\sum_{\substack{1\le i\le k\\1\le n_i\le a}}1=\sum_{1\le d\le a}\underbrace{\sum_{\substack{1\le i\le k\\1\le n_i\le a\\(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k)=d}}1}_{n_i=m_id} \\
&=\sum_{1\le d\le a}\sum_{\substack{1\le i\le k\\1\le m_i\le a/d\\(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_k)=1}}1=\sum_{1\le d\le a}N_k\left(\frac ad\right).
\end{aligned}

Now, by the [Möbius inversion formula for general convolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations), we know that for $k\ge2$,

\begin{aligned}
N_k(a)
&=\sum_{1\le d\le a}\mu(d)\left\lfloor\frac ad\right\rfloor^k=a^k\sum_{1\le d\le a}{\mu(d)\over d^k}+O\left\{a^{k-1}\sum_{1\le d\le a}{1\over d^{k-1}}\right\} \\
&={a^k\over\zeta(k)}+O\left\{a^k\int_a^\infty{\mathrm du\over u^k}\right\}+O\left\{a^{k-1}\sum_{1\le d\le a}\frac1d\right\}.
\end{aligned}

Finally, simplifying the integral gives

$$
N_k(a)={a^k\over\zeta(k)}+O(a^{k-1}\log a),
$$

Thus, if $P(a,k)$ denote the probability you are asking, then for $k\ge2$, as $a\to+\infty$,

$$
P(a,k)={N_k(a)\over\lfloor a\rfloor^k}={1\over\zeta(k)}+O(a^{1-k}\log a),
$$

where the O constant depends on neither $a$ nor $k$.

P.S. The log factor in the error term can be removed when $k\ge3$.

Comment: do you know answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422353/on-probability-of-coprimality-of-a-list-of-numbers?